# How to minimize an optimizer in a multigpu distribution

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, multi-gpu

I'm trying to adapt a DL model of MNIST to be run in many GPUs at once.
However, I can't find a way to make it work. I am new to DL so I don't fully understand all the logic behind this code. I've tried many things but none seemed to work. This is the code:

```py
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with strategy.scope():
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
  # LINES TO MAKE MODEL...
  y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

  #Crossentropy
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
  
  train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

I obtain this problem:

```
RuntimeError: Use `_distributed_apply()` instead of `apply_gradients()` in a cross-replica context.
```

Adapting the minimize function to use this `_distributed_apply()` function does not solve this issue. If I change

```
  #train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

to

```
  opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4)
  grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
  train_step = opt._distributed_apply(strategy, grads_and_vars)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/baq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py", line 108, in _make_tensor_into_per_replica
    device = input_tensor.device
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'device'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multigpu.py", line 97, in <module>
    train_step = opt._distributed_apply(strategy, grads_and_vars)
  File "/home/baq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 665, in _distributed_apply
    ds_reduce_util.ReduceOp.SUM, grads_and_vars)
  File "/home/baq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1254, in batch_reduce_to
    return self._batch_reduce_to(reduce_op, value_destination_pairs)
  File "/home/baq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py", line 739, in _batch_reduce_to
    reduce_op, value_destination_pairs)
  File "/home/baq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py", line 285, in batch_reduce
    value_destination_pairs)
  File "/home/baq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py", line 133, in _normalize_value_destination_pairs
    per_replica = _make_tensor_into_per_replica(pair[0])
  File "/home/baq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py", line 110, in _make_tensor_into_per_replica
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert `input_tensor` to a `PerReplica` object "
ValueError: Cannot convert `input_tensor` to a `PerReplica` object because it doesn't have device set.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Which TensorFlow version are you using? Seems like 1.x. Is it intentional?

Comment: I'm guessing you did go through the docs already. - [TF - distributed_training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training)                                                                   And blogs - [Scale training on multiple GPUs](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-scale-training-on-multiple-gpus-dae1041f49d2)

Comment: > "tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])"

> "tf.train.AdamOptimizer"

This is TF1 code. Please don't build anything new in TF1.

Comment: You're looking for this doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training